# Terminal command Browserify is creating an empty output file?

Tags: node.js, browserify

Folder I am in is srcstocks

```
MacBook-Air-6:srcstocks user$ browserify stocksite.js > bundle.js
```

It creates a file called bundle.js which is empty, whereas I want that file to clone stocksite.js